# Slicing two squares in half equally on a cartesian plane (finding midpoint)

Tags: java, plane, cartesian

I am working through the solution to the following problem:

> Given two squares on a two-dimensional plane, find a line that would
>   cut these two squares in half. Assume that the top and the bottom
>   sides of the square run parallel to the x-axis.

This is the solution in the book:

```
public class Square {
    public double left;
    public double top;
    public double bottom;
    public double right;
    public double size;
    public Square(double left, double top, double size) {
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.bottom = top + size;
        this.right = left + size;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Point middle() {
        return new Point((this.left + this.right)/2.0, (this.top + this.bottom)/2.0);
    }

    public boolean contains(Square other) {
        if (this.left <= other.left && this.right >= other.right && this.top <= other.top && this.bottom >= other.bottom) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Return the point where the line segment connecting mid1 and
     * mid2 intercepts the edge of square 1. That is, draw a line 
     * from mid2 to mid1, and continue it out until the edge of
     * the square. */
    public Point extend(Point mid1, Point mid2, double size) {
        /* Find what direction the line mid2 -> mid1 goes */
        double xdir = mid1.x < mid2.x ? -1 : 1;
        double ydir = mid1.y < mid2.y ? -1 : 1;

        /* If mid1 and mid2 have the same x value, then the slope
         * calculation will throw a divide by 0 exception. So, we
         * compute this specially. */
        if (mid1.x == mid2.x) {
            return new Point(mid1.x, mid1.y + ydir * size / 2.0);
        }
        double slope = (mid1.y - mid2.y) / (mid1.x - mid2.x);
        double x1 = 0;
        double y1 = 0;

        /* Calculate slope using the equation (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2).
         * Note: if the slope is “steep” (>1) then the end of the
         * line segment will hit size / 2 units away from the middle
         * on the y axis. If the slope is “shallow” (<1) the end of
         * the line segment will hit size / 2 units away from the
         * middle on the x axis. */
        if (Math.abs(slope) == 1) {
            x1 = mid1.x + xdir * size / 2.0;
            y1 = mid1.y + ydir * size / 2.0;
        } else if (Math.abs(slope) < 1) {
            x1 = mid1.x + xdir * size / 2.0;
            y1 = slope * (x1 - mid1.x) + mid1.y; 
        } else {
            y1 = mid1.y + ydir * size / 2.0;
            x1 = (y1 - mid1.y) / slope + mid1.x;
        }
        return new Point(x1, y1);
    }

    public Line cut(Square other) {
        /* Calculate where a line between each middle would collide with the edges of the squares */
        Point p1 = extend(this.middle(), other.middle(), this.size);
        Point p2 = extend(this.middle(), other.middle(), -1 * this.size);
        Point p3 = extend(other.middle(), this.middle(), other.size);
        Point p4 = extend(other.middle(), this.middle(), -1 * other.size);

        /* Of above points, find start and end of lines. Start is farthest left (with top most as a tie breaker)
         * and end is farthest right (with bottom most as a tie breaker */
        Point start = p1;
        Point end = p1;     
        Point[] points = {p2, p3, p4};
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            if (points[i].x < start.x || (points[i].x == start.x && points[i].y < start.y)) {
                start = points[i];
            } else if (points[i].x > end.x || (points[i].x == end.x && points[i].y > end.y)) {
                end = points[i];
            }
        }

        return new Line(start, end);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + left + ", " + top + ")|(" + right + "," + bottom + ")";
    }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. What is the size parameter in the extend function? The size of what? A side? The entire square (how can we quantify the size of the entire square?) Area?
2. In the cut() function, what are p1 through p4 ultimately doing? And why do we need 4 points to do it?

Comment: I don't even understand what is left, right, bottom, top in Square datatype. Does this represent a point? but how?. Is it a size? but why?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem, it's necessary and sufficient for the line to connect the two centres.

> Assume that the top and the bottom sides of the square run parallel to the x-axis.

I'm not aware of why this assumption is necessary.

Comment: I think that the reason is not to have a diamond

Comment: I understand that drawing a line between the two centers will cut the squares in half, but I had a few more specific questions that I would hope to be answered.

Comment: @Jorge Campos "I think that the reason is not to have a diamond" Again, I'm not aware of why this is necessary. For instance, if you take the average of the 4 corners the result is the centre.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not be relevant to the TS. But in case if you are also wondering about this answer, the parameter "size" is misleading - it is referring to the length of the square (Eg. 3x3 square has the length of 3.) Why four points? Because the question assumes that the line here represents the two "farest" points that cut across two squares. Each square has two points that has the potential to become start/end of the line.